# name space React has no exported member 'node'

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I'm trying to make a function do debug recoil state. I'm copying the debug observer from recoil

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRecoilSnapshot } from 'recoil'

function DebugObserver(): React.node {
    const snapshot = useRecoilSnapshot()
    useEffect(() => {
        console.debug('The following atoms were modified:')
        for (const node of snapshot.getNodes_UNSTABLE({ isModified: true })) {
            console.debug(node.key, snapshot.getLoadable(node))
        }
    }, [snapshot])

    return null
}
export default DebugObserver
```

got error name space React has no exported member 'node'

[image]

I also installed `@types/react": "^17.0.20"` already.

What am I missing ?

Comment: it is React.Node it starts with uppercase letter. it is industry standard!

Comment: capitalize `Node` also doesn't help

Comment: try React.ReactNode

Answer (score 0):

`.ReactNode` in of `.node` will do the job.